# How to combine $inc and $sort operators in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to combine the `$inc` and `$sort` operators in Mongoose so that I can both increment a value in a nested array and sort that nested array in one operation?

I know it's possible to combine `$push` and `$sort` to push a value to a nested array and sort that nested array in one operation as such:

```
User.update({ _id: user }, 
  { $push: 
    { friends: 
      { $each: [...], 
        $sort: { challengeCount: -1 } 
      }
    }
  }, 
  { upsert: true }, callback);
```

Is there a way to do something similar when incrementing a nested value in an array? For example,

```
User.where({ _id: userId, "segments.id": segmentId })
  .update({ 
    $inc: { 'segments.$.count': 1 },
    $sort: { 'segments.$.count': '-1' }
  }, callback);
```

`$sort` is not being used correctly in the latter example, just trying to demonstrate my intentions.

Thanks!